# Significato di "pettola" in questo testo

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Quella? Ma porta ancora la **pettola** in culo, rise Diodata. Quel figlio cosí bello l'avrebbe ceduto malvolentieri a un'altra, e ora si accorgeva che di femmine non capiva proprio niente. Gliel'avrebbe cercata lei una moglie come dio comanda, ma Colino, contrariamente al solito, fu irremovibile. Voleva quella.

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00226.jpg) ho trovato che "pettola" è un regionalismo con cui si denota la

> Pasta  distesa  col  matterello, sfoglia

ma questo non ha senso nel contesto del brano. Si menziona, però, che può anche significare

> ‘lembo della camicia’,  ‘gonnella’, ‘falda’

Tuttavia, non mi è chiaro il significato di questo vocabolo nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Immagino che la frase pronunciata dalla madre faccia riferimento al fatto che Candida, la ragazza che Colino le aveva indicato che voleva sposare, era ancora una bambina. La faccenda ha luogo nell'Italia postunitaria, quindi potrebbe avere a che fare con l'abbigliamento tipico di una ragazzina.